# How to detect iPhone OS version in the app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I would like to detect iPhone OS version in the app, can you post sample code as well. I tried using macro that didn't help.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to use the macros if you want conditional compilation:

```
 #if __IPHONE_8_0
 // Works on >= version 8.0
 #else
 // Works on < version 8.0
 #endif
```

Or alternatively, to check at runtime, use:

```
float ver = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (ver >= 8.0) {
    // Only executes on version 8 or above.
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that #ifdef works? I just tried __IPHONE_8_0 and the code compiled on 7.0 and caused a crash.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Late response, but since this question still comes up, the #ifdef check here is basically equivalent to __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED. There's also an __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED compile time check.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the compile-time checks given in other answers, you can use the Swift's `@available` attribute to add new functionality starting at a specific OS version.

```
if (@available(iOS 13.4, *)) {
    // Only executes above version 13.4.
}
```

[Here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-availability-checking)'s a decent summary of the evolution of OS version checking and usage.